# How to figure out after homebrew, I have double paths for git?

Tags: git, macos, homebrew

Initially I install `git` with the Xcode commandline tools. Therefore, if I did

```
> which git
/usr/bin/git
```

I decided that I wanted to use homebrew's git (and then uninstall Xcode's git). So I did `brew install git`. Now if I do

```
> which git
/usr/local/bin/git
```

So now I am using homebrew's git. However if I do

```
> which -a git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/local/bin/git
/usr/bin/git
```

Now I have `/usr/local/bin/git` twice. Where is that coming from? Also how would I figure it out myself? (I haven't uninstalled the Xcode's git yet).

I'm not sure if this information will help

```
> echo $PATH
/usr/local/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/TeX/texbin
> cat /etc/paths
/usr/local/bin
/usr/bin
/bin
/usr/sbin
/sbin
```

Comment: actually I noticed this doubling for other things that I brewed (vim, python)

Answer (score 0):

Actually my bad... I did `echo $PATH` and `cat /etc/paths` on an old terminal window. But when I did it on a new terminal, then i found that `/usr/local/bin` was repeated twice. Apparently, there was a line in my .bash_profile that prepended `/usr/local/bin` when `/usr/local/bin` had already been prepended.

Anyways deleted that line and it works now.

But I heard that `all the binaries that will be loaded the first time around will be ignored when it is visited last` when your computer goes through your $PATH for commands from http://alistapart.com/article/the-path-to-enlightenment . So even though there was two `/usr/local/bin`, it should have ignored the second one right?